# What is the appropriate way to run a program that checks for a string inside of a text file?

Tags: java, string, count, text-files, word-count

I had to make a program that searches for a specific string, that the user inputs using a scanner, inside of a text file, and returns the number of times said string has been used in the text file.  while trying to work it out in countless ways I somehow ended up with the program running but it asked me twice for the input and always only came back with "1". I worked at it so it has become a method but I'm not sure how to run this method since it does call on a text file and string of a users choice. This is what ive came up with so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class WordCount 
{


    public static int countWord(File dataFile, String WordToSearch) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
        int count = 0;
        dataFile = new File("text.txt");
        Scanner FileInput = new Scanner(dataFile);
        while (FileInput.hasNextLine()) 
{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String search = s.next();
            if (search.equals(WordToSearch))
                count++;

        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

This is the contents of the text file Im trying to call on
"Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye Hi Hello Goodbye"

please let me know if you spot any mistakes I might've missed in the code, Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: if you `break` then the `while` loop will be escaped from.

Comment: Well, **this** is certainly a problem: `public static void main(String[] args) {}`

Comment: Also correct your indentation, so you (and we) can see the intended flow.  Now after @HovercraftFullOfEels edited your post you should be able to see the the loop breaks (unconditionally) after one iteration

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Did you use a debugger? If so, where's the problem? If not, why not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a "please find mistakes in my code" site. You must tell what problems you're having and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I dont understand how to run this code, as right now it is a method. i took off the public static void main(String[] args) {} and i also took off the Break;

Comment: Why would you take out the `main` method? That's how you run your code. Run the `countWord` method from inside the `main` method.

Comment: thats the part that confuses me, do i run it as countWord (text.txt, "hello"); or is there another way to run it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `dataFile` parameter, since you're just hardcoding the file in; but to run it, yes, you would just place `countWord (text.txt, "hello");` in the `main` method.

Comment: im sincerely sorry if im a bother but can you please explain what this means as it is the error im getting trying to run the code. 

error: <identifier> expected

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem is that `if` you find a line that matches you `break;` the loop. Because of this your counter will never exceed 1.

Instead you should remove the `break;` from your code then the `while` loop will run through all the lines.

EDIT:

The following code has been tested and works. Overall points worth noting are:

**A.** The main class is the first class that loads and therefore must run anything you want to run at the programs start. Also the main class must be static.

**B.** I have changed the `Scanner` you were using to instead a `BufferedReader` and a `FileReader` these are different classes that are also designed to read files contents.

**C.** My `while` loop only `breaks;` when it reaches the end of the file. If you `break` before then it will stop the search from finding all the occurrences.

**D.** I do not know exactly what you are trying to find. For example if you want to find entire lines that are equal to your word or entire lines that contain your word, etc. (if you tell me more specifically how you would like to refine your search i can update the code)

// When packaging you seriously reduce the size of your program if you don't import the entire java packages
// here i have narrowed down the io* and util* to actually be the things you need

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ScannerInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // the main method is the first that is run.
        // the main method MUST be static
        // inside the main method put whatever you want to run in your program

        scan(); // we run the scanner method which is created below
    }

    public static void scan() {
            // first i create a scanner so that the java command prompt can take input
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter file path to file and file name: "); //prompt the reader to type the file directory and name
            File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // determine what file they want based on that name

            System.out.println("Enter the line you want to find: "); //prompt the reader to type the line they want to count
            String line = input.nextLine(); // determine what line they want based on that string

            // this statement tells them how many occurances there are
            // this is done by the countWord() method (which when run returns a integer)
            System.out.println("There are " + countWord(file, line) + " occurances.");

            System.exit(0); // ends the program
    }

    // the countWord method takes a file name and word to search and returns an integer
    public static int countWord(File dataFile, String WordToSearch) {

        int count = 0; // start are counter

        // NOTE: i prefer a BufferedReader to a Scanner you can change this if you want

        // load the buffered reader
        BufferedReader FileInput = null;
        try {
            // attempt to open the file which we have been told about
            FileInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // if the file does not exist a FileNotFoundException will occur
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerInt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // then try searching the file
        try {
            // this while loop runs forever until it is broken below
            while (true) {
                String search = FileInput.readLine(); // we read a line and store it

                if (search == null) { // if the line is "null" that means the file has ended and their are no more lines so break
                    break;
                }

                // then we check if this line has the text

                // NOTE: i do not know what exactly you want to do here but currently this checks if the entire line
                // is exactly equal to the string. This means though that if their are other words on the line it will not count

                // Alternatively you can use search.contains(WordToSearch)
                // that will check if the "WordToSearch" is anywhere in the line. Unfortunately that will not record if there is more than one

                // (There is one more option but it is more complex but i will only mention it if you find the other two do not work)
                if (search.equals(WordToSearch)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // if the line it tries to read does not exist a IOException will occur
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerInt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            FileInput.close(); // close the file reader
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // if the FileInput reader has broken and therefore can not close a IOException will occur
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerInt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Considering that there is nothing in the `main` method, I doubt it will work.

Comment: Correct. I have edited it. I believe the user had more code which he did not post.

Comment: I am confused as to how to run this method, i tried using this but to no avail

Comment: No problem, i will make it work and then post the code (it probably will take a few minutes)

Comment: ok thank you so much, but please do explain as i want to learn and use the knowledge in the future

Comment: @user3663055: your question suggests that you need to read/study a basic Java textbook or tutorial as you're missing fundamental concepts in how to use the language. Please for your own good, walk away from this site and learn the basics as they will serve you much better than having us write code for you or try to teach you things that this site is not geared to do.

Comment: @user3663055 - i have updated the code to run fully and have put in comments to explain what i have done. If you have any questions feel free to comment.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam - I have now edited my post to be fully functional. As you pointed out before, the main method needs to actually have something in it ;)